# Default value for Twitter's max_id Parameter?

Tags: twitter

Is there a default value for Twitter's newish max_id parameter?

I've tried:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=justinbieber&trim_user=true&count=200&max_id=false

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=justinbieber&trim_user=true&count=200&max_id=null

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=justinbieber&trim_user=true&count=200&max_id=9999999999999999999999

I just want it to return exactly what it would return if you didn't use a max_id at all:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=justinbieber&trim_user=true&count=200

Biebs is counting on you...

Comment: "Biebs is counting on you..." Ha, very nice. It's rare there is (intentional) humor in a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a default. If you want the result as if you didn't use max_id, then don't send the max_id. It's purpose is for pagination, so if you ran

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=justinbieber&trim_user=true&count=200&max_id=216942783313883136

at any time, you are going to get the same 200 results. If you only care about the most recent 200 then don't bother with it.

Comment: and btw it is linked with the id_str property returned in the results not the id property.

Comment: Thanks - thats what i figured. For my program it would've been a touch cleaner to put some sort of default value if it existed, but alas.